# Converting entity to dto in java

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

It is taking lot of time in converting entity to dto.
Because entity have many relations.so the child tables data is being assigned to dto properties.
Is there any best way to do this..
I have gone through model mapper also ..but model mapper maps direct entity to dto properties.it cannot map the child tables data to dto.

Comment: It depends on what do you need the DTO for. Do you really need to have all the data in the Entity also in the DTO? For instance, in a web app the DTO might be used on the client side, and usually you don't need to have a DTO that contains all the information of the Entity.

Comment: You'd need to show some code to illustrate, what your difficulty is. As it stands now, it is completely unclear what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

> but model mapper maps direct entity to dto properties.it cannot map the child tables data to dto.

You can use [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/). It maps the child too.

Per example, this works:

```
GrandchildEntity grandchildEntity = new GrandchildEntity(13);
ChildEntity childEntity = new ChildEntity("Child Name", grandchildEntity);
ParentEntity parentEntity = new ParentEntity("Parent Name", "Parent Address", childEntity);

ParentDto parentDto = new ModelMapper().map(parentEntity, ParentDto.class);
```

`ParentDto` have `ChildDto` and `ChildDto` have `GrandchildDto`, all of them with the same field names of the entities. All fields are correctly filled on Dtos after called `map` method.

You can configure `ModelMapper` to use reflection, but by default you need a empty constructor and the `set` method for each field on Dto. In the entities you need the `get` method for each field.